# Jenkins deploy per branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a PHP application that will be using Jenkins and GitHub to automatically deploy every time when pushed.

I am working on a branch so if I push any changes I want to deploy to branch.test.com and see the changes right away.

I am trying to use "Execute Shell" in Jenkins so after build, it finds out which branch ('master' or 'develop') is updated and copies it to the `www` folder to reflect the changes.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Implicitly, you're controlling your deploy process with Jenkins, right?  Normally I've heard it used just for tests and publishing artifacts.

Comment: @Makoto, Jenkins can also be used for continuous integration (CI), so what he's describing doesn't sound so bad to me...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are on the right track. Jenkins can be used for Continuous Delivery (CD) and doing build/deploy/test process per branch is a good practice.

I suggest you to use separate jobs for each branch. Even [Jenkins Best Practices page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Best+Practices) says this:

> One of advantages of using CI tools is to detect problems early in the development lifecycle. Setting up a different job/project for each branch you create will help to maximize the benefit of detecting problems early as part of supporting parallel development efforts and reducing risk.

Usually, project grows and becomes to have a lot of branches and at some point you will need to automate a process of creation a bunch of jobs for each branch. Here are few articles that will help:

- [Auto-create Jenkins build jobs for new feature
  branches](http://entagen.github.io/jenkins-build-per-branch/)
- [Jenkins build and deploy script per Github branch](https://gist.github.com/edaooo/39bb5feda1506f16b6f0a9b15ef08d6a)
- [Jenkins autojobs](https://pythonhosted.org/jenkins-autojobs/)
- [Jenkins DSL Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Vitalii Elenhaupt is good.
I just want to elaborate more on what I was doing.
I've found my own answer while I'm digging Jenkins.

In "Excute shell" Using following code will deploy files to "branch" in own server in this case.

```
echo ${GIT_BRANCH##origin/}
rm -rf /home/www/${GIT_BRANCH##origin/}/* > /dev/null
rsync -av --exclude='.git' ${WORKSPACE}/ /home/www/${GIT_BRANCH##origin/}
```

If it gets busier then I might create a separate job for each branch as Vitalii Elenhaupt suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can select a **"Multibranch Pipeline"** and filter by branch name. Something like in the image below. In my case, what worked best was to choose a normal git repository (versus Github, Gitlab, etc).

[image]